# Format 11 digit numbers with sed and RegEx

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I'm writing a script that can convert numbers (with 11 digits) like this:

Example input:

```
11111111111
12345678900
```

Example output:

```
(11) 1 1111-1111
(12) 3 4567-8900
```

And here's the command I'm using:

```
echo "$(sed 's/\(..\)\(.\{5\}\)/(\1)\2-/g' $file)"
```

But the output is:

```
(11)11111-1111
(12)34567-8900
```

Anyone can help me on how to isolate the third number with spaces as the example output? All I can use is sed and RegEx. Thank you!

Comment: A little push in the right direction with GNU sed: `sed -E 's/(.{2})(.)(.{4})(.{4})/\1 \2 \3 \4/' file`

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following, using `sed`'s back reference capability here.

```
sed -E 's/^([0-9]{2})([0-9])([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})$/(\1) \2 \3-\4/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `-E` option for using extended regex with `sed` here. Then using `sed`'s back reference capability here. Where Creating 4 capturing groups here(which has 2,1,4,4 digits in it respectively). Then while substituting it, using necessary string(s) eg--> adding `(` and `)` before and after 1st captured value and so on to make it same as per OP's ask.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -E 's/^(..)(.)(....)(.*)$/\(\1\) \2 \3\-\4/g' "file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` and a regex seems needlessly complicated here. If the numbers are all completely uniform, just print the substrings with the adornments added.

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { split("(_) _ _-", f, /_/); split("2_1_4_4", l, /_/); }
{ n=1; for(i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    printf "%s%s", f[i], substr($1, n, l[i]); n+=l[i] }
  printf "\n" }' file
```

The `BEGIN` block creates two parallel data structures which drive the body of the script. The first `f` contains the prefix to add before the next slice of the substring, and the second `l` contains the lengths of the substrings we want to extract.

If you wanted to really make this simple, you could write it out as

```
awk '{
    printf "(%s", substr($0, 1, 2);
    printf ") %s", substr($0, 3, 1);
    printf " %s", substr($0, 4, 4);
    printf "-%s\n", substr($0, 8);
}' file
```

The regex solution is definitely more succinct, but spelling things out so you understand them is probably more important than notational compactness in most situations.